# Node-RED action not fired after rule on Watson IoT Platform

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red, watson, watson-iot

I'm currently using Watson IoT Platform to collect datas from my raspberrypi.

I created a rule based on a threshold and three actions if the rule is activated:

- the first one is a Node-RED action invoking a Node-RED node on Bluemix
- the second one is another Node-RED action invoking a Node-RED node on my raspberry pi
- the third one is a simple "send mail"

The first two actions are never fired while the email is always correctly sent.

My Node-RED node on BlueMix is at the following url: https://xxx.eu-gb.mybluemix.net and the http endpoint is /command so the URL I configured is https://xxx.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/command.

What is wrong with this configurations?

Thanks,

Diego

Comment: Is your http in endpoint a POST?  It must be.  I would run `bx cf logs appname` and trigger the event and see what the logs say.

Comment: Hi @amadain, you are right, I was using a GET as an endpoint. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The http in node must use **POST** as the method.  Here is a sample flow which when triggered writes to a debug node.

```
[{"id":"7ad184c7.c898cc","type":"debug","z":"ed48ac5f.aa6c68","name":"","active":true,"console":"false","complete":"false","x":443.9000244140625,"y":289.79998779296875,"wires":[]},{"id":"f269a1cd.d46d5","type":"function","z":"ed48ac5f.aa6c68","name":"","func":"msg.payload= \"Hello from my IoT Platform Rule\";\nreturn msg;\n","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":396.90000915527344,"y":201.59999084472656,"wires":[["aa867d6d.2b6518","7ad184c7.c898cc"]]},{"id":"e9a7c24c.2c8128","type":"http in","z":"ed48ac5f.aa6c68","name":"/inventory","url":"/inventory","method":"post","swaggerDoc":"","x":203.90000915527344,"y":206.99998474121094,"wires":[["f269a1cd.d46d5"]]},{"id":"aa867d6d.2b6518","type":"http response","z":"ed48ac5f.aa6c68","name":"","x":578.9000091552734,"y":207.40000915527344,"wires":[]}]
```

Comment: Hi Amadain, I'm not able anymore to invoke the webservice from Watson IoT to the NodeRED http in node on my Raspberry Pi. Is it changed something in the Watson IoT Platform? How can I debug actions?

Comment: Mine still works.  Probably I'd restart the Pi and if that doesn't help log a ticket.  Or a new post.